# How to get Django Query description into a field

Tags: django, django-queryset

In Django, I have for example a query:

```
 qs=Member.Active_objects.filter(resigndate__isnull=False)
```

I would like to find some sort of function that returns information about the query that I can print with the output, e.g.

```
qsdetails=somefunction(qs)
```

and return something like:

```
qsdetails="Member.Active_objects.filter(resigndate__isnull=False)"
```

or something more descriptive, if that is what comes out of this function.

Does such a function exist? I've searched through the Django Documentation and can't spot anything.

Comment: You can do (qs.query) and get the sql query that will be produced.

Comment: Wondering why Dr.Elch needed to edit my entry?  Puzzle.